# How can I resize big images on fancyzoom ? ( code provided )

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I resize big images for example larger than 1000x1000 pixels?

```
jQuery.fn.fancyZoom = function(options){

  var options   = options || {};
  var directory = options && options.directory ? options.directory : 'images';
  var zooming   = false;

  if ($('#zoom').length == 0) {
    var ext = $.browser.msie ? 'gif' : 'png';
    var html = '<div id="zoom" style="display:none;"> \
                  <table id="zoom_table" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; height:100%;"> \
                    <tbody> \
                      <tr> \
                        <td class="tl" style="background:url(' + directory + '/tl.' + ext + ') 0 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                        <td class="tm" style="background:url(' + directory + '/tm.' + ext + ') 0 0 repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                        <td class="tr" style="background:url(' + directory + '/tr.' + ext + ') 100% 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                      </tr> \
                      <tr> \
                        <td class="ml" style="background:url(' + directory + '/ml.' + ext + ') 0 0 repeat-y; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                        <td class="mm" style="vertical-align:top; padding:10px;"> \
                          <div id="zoom_content"> \
                          </div> \
                        </td> \
                        <td class="mr" style="background:url(' + directory + '/mr.' + ext + ') 100% 0 repeat-y;  width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                      </tr> \
                      <tr> \
                        <td class="bl" style="background:url(' + directory + '/bl.' + ext + ') 0 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                        <td class="bm" style="background:url(' + directory + '/bm.' + ext + ') 0 100% repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                        <td class="br" style="background:url(' + directory + '/br.' + ext + ') 100% 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                      </tr> \
                    </tbody> \
                  </table> \
                  <a href="#" title="Close" id="zoom_close" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;"> \
                    <img src="' + closebutton + '" alt="Close" style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0;" /> \
                  </a> \
                </div>';

    $('body').append(html);

    $('html').click(function(e){if($(e.target).parents('#zoom:visible').length == 0) hide();});
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 27 && $('#zoom:visible').length > 0) hide();
    });

    $('#zoom_close').click(hide);
  }

  var zoom          = $('#zoom');
  var zoom_table    = $('#zoom_table');
  var zoom_close    = $('#zoom_close');
  var zoom_content  = $('#zoom_content');
  var middle_row    = $('td.ml,td.mm,td.mr');

  this.each(function(i) {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    $(this).click(show);
  });

  return this;

  function show(e) {
    if (zooming) return false;
        zooming         = true;
        var content_div = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var zoom_width  = options.width;
        var zoom_height = options.height;

        var width       = window.innerWidth || (window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth);
    var height      = window.innerHeight || (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight);
    var x           = window.pageXOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollLeft || window.document.body.scrollLeft);
    var y           = window.pageYOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.document.body.scrollTop);
    var window_size = {'width':width, 'height':height, 'x':x, 'y':y}

        var width              = (zoom_width || content_div.width()) + 60;
        var height             = (zoom_height || content_div.height()) + 60;
        var d                  = window_size;

        // ensure that newTop is at least 0 so it doesn't hide close button
        var newTop             = Math.max((d.height/2) - (height/2) + y, 0);
        var newLeft            = (d.width/2) - (width/2);
        var curTop             = e.pageY;
        var curLeft            = e.pageX;

        zoom_close.attr('curTop', curTop);
        zoom_close.attr('curLeft', curLeft);
        zoom_close.attr('scaleImg', options.scaleImg ? 'true' : 'false');

    $('#zoom').hide().css({
            position    : 'absolute',
            top             : curTop + 'px',
            left            : curLeft + 'px',
            width     : '1px',
            height    : '1px'
        });

    fixBackgroundsForIE();
    zoom_close.hide();

    if (options.closeOnClick) {
      $('#zoom').click(hide);
    }

        if (options.scaleImg) {
        zoom_content.html(content_div.html());
        $('#zoom_content img').css('width', '100%');
        } else {
          zoom_content.html('');
        }

    $('#zoom').animate({
      top     : newTop + 'px',
      left    : newLeft + 'px',
      opacity : "show",
      width   : width,
      height  : height
    }, 500, null, function() {
      if (options.scaleImg != true) {
            zoom_content.html(content_div.html());
        }
            unfixBackgroundsForIE();
            zoom_close.show();
            zooming = false;
    })
    return false;
  }

  function hide() {
    if (zooming) return false;
        zooming         = true;
      $('#zoom').unbind('click');
        fixBackgroundsForIE();
        if (zoom_close.attr('scaleImg') != 'true') {
        zoom_content.html('');
        }
        zoom_close.hide();
        $('#zoom').animate({
      top     : zoom_close.attr('curTop') + 'px',
      left    : zoom_close.attr('curLeft') + 'px',
      opacity : "hide",
      width   : '1px',
      height  : '1px'
    }, 500, null, function() {
      if (zoom_close.attr('scaleImg') == 'true') {
            zoom_content.html('');
        }
      unfixBackgroundsForIE();
            zooming = false;
    });
    return false;
  }

  function switchBackgroundImagesTo(to) {
    $('#zoom_table td').each(function(i) {
      var bg = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/\.(png|gif|none)\"\)$/, '.' + to + '")');
      $(this).css('background-image', bg);
    });
    var close_img = zoom_close.children('img');
    var new_img = close_img.attr('src').replace(/\.(png|gif|none)$/, '.' + to);
    close_img.attr('src', new_img);
  }

  function fixBackgroundsForIE() {
    if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) >= 7) {
      switchBackgroundImagesTo('gif'); 
    }
    }

  function unfixBackgroundsForIE() {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version >= 7) {
      switchBackgroundImagesTo('png'); 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do image resizing on your server, rather than doing this in JavaScript, because the larger the image, the more bytes you have to send, and therefore the slower your page will load. If you make your server accept cgi parameters for the width and height of the image and have your server perform the resizing, then you can reduce the amount of I/O, and you can also implement the resizing in  a language that can do it much faster (e.g. using C or C++ with the OpenCV library).

This would mean that your JavaScript would then consist if simply performing an appropriate XHR request for the image. If the image is small enough to be zoomed-in in JavaScript, then you can do subsequent zooms just in JavaScript using the image that was already fetched.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. However I would like not to do the server resizing and just scale down the image...